# Why Is my code not running in Python IDES

Tags: python

I have two sets of codes and I have just started learning Python for my needs:
Have two different IDEs (PyCharm Comm Edn) and PyDev,  Have Tried with both,

The 2nd set runs successfully  however 1st set doesn't, have compare both sets of code they don't differ much except for string quotes and indentation.

## 1st Set Of Code:

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self):
        self.speed = 0
        self.odometer = 0
        self.time = 0

    def say_state(self):
        print("I'm going {} kph".format(self.speed))

    def accelerate(self):
        self.speed += 5

    def brake(self):
        self.speed -= 5

    def step(self):
        self.odometer += self.speed
        self.time += 1

    def average_speed(self):
        return self.odometer / self.time

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        my_car = Car()
        print("I am a Car")

    while True:
        action = input("What Should I Do"
                       "[A]ccelerate, [B]rake show [O]dometer"
                       "Or Show average [S]peed").upper()
        if action not in "ABOS" or len(action) != 1:
            print("I DOnt Know how to do that")
            continue
        if action == 'A':
            my_car.accelerate()

        elif action == 'B':
            my_car.brake()

        elif action == 'O':
            print("My Car has driven {} Kilometers".format(my_car.odometer))

        elif action == 'S':
            print("The Car average speed was  {} Kilometers".format(my_car.average_speed()))
            my_car.step()
            my_car.say_state()
```

## 2nd Set Of Code:

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self):
        self.speed = 0
        self.odometer = 0
        self.time = 0

    def say_state(self):
        print("I'm going {} kph!".format(self.speed))

    def accelerate(self):
        self.speed += 5

    def brake(self):
        self.speed -= 5

    def step(self):
        self.odometer += self.speed
        self.time += 1

    def average_speed(self):
        return self.odometer / self.time


if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_car = Car()
    print("I'm a car!")
    while True:
        action = input("What should I do? [A]ccelerate, [B]rake, "
            "show [O]dometer, or show average [S]peed?").upper()
        if action not in "ABOS" or len(action) != 1:
            print("I don't know how to do that")
            continue
        if action == 'A':
            my_car.accelerate()
        elif action == 'B':
            my_car.brake()
        elif action == 'O':
            print("The car has driven {} kilometers".format(my_car.odometer))
        elif action == 'S':
            print("The car's average speed was {} kph".format(my_car.average_speed()))
        my_car.step()
        my_car.say_state()
```

Have tried all possible indentation for it to work.
Apology for any mistakes in the question! Here The code indentation in stackoverflow is also different.

Have Also tried the IDE's auto-indent and indenting by selecting entire code Now  I could have overlooked the set 1 and go away with set 2, but the thing here I want to know is that why on the earth, 1st set gives me the error, when the set is lexically correct.

**Error Set 1:**

```
E:\Learn_Python\venv\Scripts\python.exe E:/Python_Learning_Projects/Car.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Python_Learning_Projects/Car.py", line 1, in 
    class Car:
  File "E:/Python_Learning_Projects/Car.py", line 24, in Car
    my_car = Car()
NameError: name 'Car' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: The second set of code won't run. Did you mean to indent all the code after `if __name__ == "__main__"`?

Comment: To format text as code: paste the code to stackoverflow , select the whole code with your mouse nd press ctl+k, if you do not want to use this indentation by 4 blanks, you can put your code between `<pre>` and `</pre>` tags. This will  print your text 'as is', without any formatting (but also with any syntax highlighting)

Comment: your indentation is wrong. maybe you made some copy and paste errors. please copy your code again and format as described above. It is important that we see here the code as you  use it in your environment.

Comment: also describe the meaning of 'does not compile'. if you run your program (not compile), what happens? does it throw an error message?

Comment: As others said, your code is not properly indented. Furthermore, you say it does not work, but you did not provide the error. Please show the exact error you are getting. In addition to that, there is certainly much more code then needed to see the error, try to reduce it to a minimal example. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @BoarGules maybe my comments were not clear enough. I wanted to tell him how add the code to his post without introducing copy and paste errors. it does not make sense that you edit the question and repair all indentation errors because they may be part of his problem. At the moment we do not know this.you should rollback your edit. If you think the identation is the solution of the problem then post the modified code as answer.

Comment: @BoarGules Now the question makes even less sense because the code does not match the problem description. I am sure that is not the code the OP is trying to run.

Comment: @miracle173 Fair point. Rolled back.

Comment: @miracle173, Thanks for your responses, I have made some edits to the question, Hope this time I have made it correct, I want to know why the 1st set is not running.

Comment: @BoarGules: Thanx, I just need the point where indenting needed not full indented code.

Comment: If I indent the code it gives me an error as:
NameError: name 'Car' is not defined

Comment: @Saurabh_Jha So, you added incorrect indentation and you ask why it no longer works? Isn't that self-explanatory?

Comment: @zvone: Request to read the full question first.

Comment: Thanks everyone I got it resolved!

Comment: My Bad I didn't know indentation is so important in Python.